# associative and commutative F-algebra with basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

let $G$ be a finite-dimensional $F$-algebra and let $X=\{x_1,...,x_m\}$ be the basis. The structure constants of $G$ with respect to the basis are the scalars $f_{rsk}\in F$ for $1\leq  r,s,k\leq m$ given $x_rx_s= f_{rs1}x_1+...+f_{rsm}x_m$. What are the conditions on the structure scalars $f _{rsk}$ that are equivalent to associativity and commutativity for algebra $G$?

Comment: Just write it out. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I assume you intend it to be multiplication of the basis elements in the algebra?