# On the properties of submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with unity and $N$ be a left $R$-module. How to prove that if $K+M=L+M$ and $K\cap M=L\cap M$, then $K=L$? Where $K,L,M$ are left $R$-submodules of $N$ s.t $K\subseteq L$.

Comment: Darn I remember having it in one of my books :<

Comment: send me it! :-)

Comment: It's in swedish but I found the proof :)

Comment: Tack sa mycket ! Men jag kan ocsa svenska :)

Comment: Vafan kan du? =) http://www.math.chalmers.se/~jub/JUB-filer/KOMALG/komalgin.pdf här är länken då!

Comment: Jag har studerat i sverige flera år sedan :) Tack for länken! Kan du hjälpa mig i denna fråga också? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566847/finite-dimensional-f-algebra-with-basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $l\in L$, then we have that $k+m=l$ for some $k\in K$ and $m\in M$, this implies that $l-k=m\in M\cap L=M\cap K\subseteq K$ by that intersection of submodules is a submodule itself. Which means that $l\in K$ and we get that $L\subseteq K$ and from our premise we get that $K=L$